# I'm trying to initialize a UIViewController to be pushed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I began from a tutorial example that had a UIViewController connected to a nib, but now i've decided to do it all programmatically. Consequently, I deleted the nib but without knowing how to implement my controller.

I did something like this:

```
EventsDetailController *myChild = [[EventsDetailController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myChild animated:YES];
```

However, it crashes when I click the specific cell.

Do I have to initWith something? Before when I had a nib it was initWithNib

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface EventsDetailController : UIViewController {

    NSString *message;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *message;

@end



#import "EventsDetailController.h"


@implementation EventsDetailController
@synthesize message;


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}

-(void)viewDidLoad{


    UILabel *theMsg = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,30)];

    theMsg.text = @"hello";

    [theMsg release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)viewDidUnload{

    self.message = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];

}


-(void)dealloc{


    [message release];
    [super dealloc];

}
@end
```

Perhaps, I'll start from scratch, I think it is still looking for the nib I deleted.

Comment: Those two lines appear to be fine. I would think your problem lies elsewhere. At what line does the app crash? Perhaps it's in the implementation of EventsDetailController?

Comment: What happens when you create a class with a nib? I dont see anything added to the appdelegate. It's still looking for it.

Comment: Have you tried implementing -(id)init { self = [super init]; return self} ? Maybe it's still tied to trying to load the nib, and is crashing when it isn't found? (Or you could do a clean + rebuild, sometimes Xcode is at fault for still hanging onto that data)

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: 011-08-19 18:39:53.868 TCA_Base[5490:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "EventsDetail" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

Comment: Go into interface builder and see if there is any reference to EventsDetailController.  Also check in MainWindow.xib if the EventsDetailController object is still there.

Comment: From your error, it is basically saying that your nib isn't set up properly.  Do you still have the nib?  If so, just open it and hook up the view from the File Owner to the view in the nib and it should run fine.  Though there is one other area that might cause issues.  In your `viewDidLoad`, releasing the `theMsg` label right away might crash the program with a bad access error.  You would be better off removing `[theMsg release]` and using `UILabel *theMsg = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:....] autorelease];`.  This will release the label itself when it's no longer needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have the app delegate's `window.rootViewController` set to a `NavigationController` instance, and that instance was created with a `initWithRootViewController`, as you mentioned that you're getting to the point where it crashes when you click on a cell.

Looking at the added code, the only thing I see that's strange is in the 'veiwDidLoad' method - you alloc and release 'theMsg', but don't use it. I'm assuming you've cut out some code for brevity.

I ended up starting from scratch when I went away from .nib files (about 5 minutes after starting my first iPhone app). I would run with that, adding in your functionality a little at a time.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on. I though I could just delete the nib for this class that is loaded in a Nav controller, and that nav controller is loaded in the main tabbar.

Comment: Well, from your description, I'm still guessing it has something to do with EventsDetailController. The only thing I see that's missing is the `loadView` method - called when there's no .nib file, and used to draw the components.

Comment: Actually, there are a few other methods that are typically located in a controller that I don't see in your sample, but I'm not sure if you're omitting any code.

Comment: I just created a new project and transfered my classes over without creating a nib.